# Extract the type of a property from an interface

Tags: typescript

How can I reuse the type of `someMethod` ?

```
Interface Foo {
  someMethod: // want to reuse this type without copy pasting
}

const myValue: // I want it to be of type Foo.someMethod
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
interface Foo {
  someMethod: {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
  };
}

const myValue: Foo['someMethod'] = { bar: 0, foo: '' };
```